# how to bind a repeater inside a repeater on the basis of values from the first repeater

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

student code| student.Name |Region Name|Location Name|  Assets Details |

I have to display asset details on the basis of each student. There can be more than one asset details for one student, how can i use this in repeater or gridview.

Table which i have in SQL.

Student Code     |    student name    |    Asset Details
1                                                   Ray                                      laptop
1                                                    Ray                                      Bed
2                                                      Raj                                       Phone
2                                                      Raj                                    charger\
   
....
I want to display asset details for each unique student code like this on my page.
Student Code | student name | Asset Details

1                                                Ray                                 laptop
                                                                                                      Bed
2                                                Raj                                     Phone
                                                                         
                                   Charger

How do i perform the same with only one hit from sql.?

Comment: Select Data for parent repeater and child repeater in the same stored procedure but in different table. bind first repeater with its Table , say Table[0], and in ItemDataBound event of parent repeater bind child repeater By applying LINQ on Table[1].

Comment: take two repeater  one repeater inside repeater ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

Use a stored procedure to return two results set for the following queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentCode, studentname FROM StudentInfo

SELECT StudentCode, student name, Asset Details
```

Create a DataSet for the results with 2 tables. You can name the first table "Student" and the second table "StudentInfo"

Create a relationship for the tables (please use the intellisense for syntax)

```
DataSet.Relationships.Add("RelationshipName",Table1.StudentCode,Table2.StudentCode)
```

Bind the GridView with the DataSet

Create a Template column for Asset Details and insert a repeater or Gridview for that column.

On the `ItemDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.ItemData;
Repeater.DataSource = dv.CreateChildView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two repeater control, try to make a sql query to get data in this format
use such query

```
select studentID, 
       stuff((select ',' + AssetDetails
                  from Tbl_Student t2 
                  where t2.studentID= t1.studentID
                  order by studentID
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as AssetDetailsString
    from Tbl_Student t1
    group by studentID
```

this will return single row for every studentID with Assestdetails in CSV format in same row